# Remove white border around thumbnail in Generic Passbook?

Tags: ios, ios6, passbook

For some reason the pass automatically puts a white border around the thumbnail image we put in the passbook and I didn't find any reference for that in the documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete documentation of the passbook format can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/Introduction.html

I could only find the suppressStripShine option, but nothing related to this border. So most likely the modification you seek is not currently supported. File a Radar.

Comment: I can confirm that you cannot remove it, it's just not supported but Apple.

Answer (score 2):

Thumbnail without white border seems available in the pass style called Event Ticket. See image at http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/1807rfmzhutezjpg/original.jpg for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is resolved by now, since there aren't any white borders on iOS anymore.. However, they still exist on macOS (when opening a *.pkpass* file)..
Didn't found anything to remove them from there either...